# How to make Steam not count some games towards "Avg. Game Completion Rate"?

Tags: steam, achievements

In Steam, some of the Showcases show the Avg. Game Completion Rate. This takes into account the percentage of achievements you have in average of all your games.

Is there any way to make it not count some games? Sometimes you install games (specially free ones) and find them quite boring and stop playing them. It feels a bit annoying to see a low average due to them.

Comment: I doubt many people consider the Avg. Game Completion Rate all that meaningful. It's not like Xbox's Gamerscore or anything. People are more likely to be impressed by hard to get achievements, particularly for games they've played. But you should also consider the fact that very few people are ever likely to view your profile on Steam.

Comment: Although, you are technically right since you used the comparative: "many people."

I for one am someone that is bothered by this metric, as an achiever.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to user Lorean at [Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864974467434899969/#c864980009904968004):

> A quite late response, but I keep a spreadsheet to track my achievements and I just tested this. with some functions. Dividing completed achievements vs total achievements gives me 40%. Calculating the average of each individual game's achievement completion % gives a result of 52.11% which would match with my profile's average completion rate of 52%.

And furthermore, to answer your question. User Canti in the same [thread](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864974467434899969/#c666827315593082115):

> Games that have no achievements are not factored in at all.
>
> Likewise, games you have not earned any achievements in are also not counted. Only when you get 1 achievement will the game start to count it towards your average.

**So games without any completed achievements do not count towards the Avg. Game Completion Rate.**

More examples are given in the same thread. Here is user [Boys Dont Cry](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864974467434899969/#c624075036481101452):

> I can confirm it's the average completion of all games played with achievements.
>   Games with 0 ach. doesn't count
>   But F2P and demo not any longer available like Call of Duty: Black Ops - Multier (I got 2 out of 3) is included in the total and the completion Rate
>
> For games there I have at least 1 achievement:
>   I have 1428 of max 2270 => 63%
>   but average of percentage for each game => 68% same as on my profile page

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even though I was wondering is thare any way to make games with some completed achievements, but that you have no longer installed and don't expect to ever play again don't count.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans I don't think so. That would also not be very fair, because it isn't your *real* average completion rate anymore, just for games you think are eligible. I think that the way Steam handles it now, without counting games without achievements (so not played, or played for just mere minutes), is as fair as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately - no.  There is no way to remove the "ghost" of achievements affecting your AGC ratio on Steam.  Using some kind of unlock/relocker tool to wipe a game's achievements will actually only harm your AGC because if you have ever had 1 achievement in a game, it will forever affect your AGC and by taking yourself to 0%, you have only lowered it.  Valve will not wipe/clear achievements for you if you contact them via support.  Games where the DEVELOPER chooses to remove some or all achievements will properly update their affect on your AGC, however.

All of this confirmed via the complex stats on the https://completionist.me tracker and through extensive testing by the 100Pals official Steam achievement hunting community: https://www.discord.me/100Pals

Answer (score 0):

There's no legitimate method that you can use however there are third party tools available that you can use to re-lock achievements. So you can set the earned achievements for any given game to zero but I'm unsure how long/or if this will effect the showcase in question.

Comment: Isn't using a third party tool to edit your achievements against Steam's T&Cs?

Comment: I'm honestly unsure whether or not its specifically mentioned which is partly why I neither named nor linked any of the options. It may not be an option they want to pursue but it is there. If people just answer that it's not possible then they aren't correct. I however have answered the question, noting that it is on fact possible. It's then on the user to do what they will with that information.

Comment: Not only that, but its apparently been confirmed by other users; that steam back-end servers remember anyway....So the tool actually makes it worse for you. At least for this metric.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few methods if you really want to try. I haven't actually tested either one but you can try them out pretty safely without harming your AGC (more on that at the end).

1. The simplest one, which is the less likely one to work, is to always play the game in Offline Mode and see if it will affect your AGC.
2. The one more likely to work is to block access to steamcommunity.com in your firewall while you're playing the game you wish not to be counted towards your AGC. Why am I suggesting this? Well, because I've experienced this first hand with a game that I DID want to be counted towards my AGC and it DIDN'T. Once, I was playing a game to get a certain achievement (which was not easy to get either), and even though I had done what was necessary for that achievement, I did not receive it because SteamCommunity was down at the time. So I had to wait for SteamCommunity to come back online to play for and obtain the achievement again, for it to finally be registered on my account and counted towards my AGC. Which was very frustrating btw.
3. And the one that I think is guaranteed to work is to create another account that you do not care about and use the Family Library Sharing feature in Steam to share your entire game library with that other account. This way you'll be able to play any game in your library, you don't want to be counted towards your main account's AGC, on your secondary account.

So, feel free to give the first two a try (if you really want to play on your main account at all times) on some achievement that's very easy to get, on a game that is already counted towards your AGC so you won't mess it up for no good reason.

PS. I understand why one would want this and NO, it's not cheating. I too have games that I absolutely suck at, but that I would like to play anyway without wrecking my AGC. Doing this will, by no means, give me a 100% AGC because there will always be games I'm good at and which I enjoy playing, that I will not be able to obtain all the achievements for. And that's ok. But I would really like for my AGC to reflect my performance in games that I really do spend time on to collect as many achievements as possible and not games that I merely toy or experiment with.

Update: I just tried option #3 and I can confirm that it's working.

Comment: The 3rd option will probably work, but I think playing data is simply logged client-side and communicated every time Steam comes online. So I think 1 and 2 won't work.