# Is there a way to list my removed games on Steam?

Tags: steam

Minutes ago I asked [Do removed games still count towards Achievements Status on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300749/removed-games-still-count-to-achievements-status-on-steam/300752?noredirect=1#comment425695_300752)

The answer sadly is *yes*.

So is it possible to list all my **removed** games on Steam?

EDIT: 
These games are not in my library, in the past i removed them using https://help.steampowered.com/ (I relinquished the license/returned for refund/deauthorized) so I need to buy to play again

**EDIT and Solution:**

The solution I found was see my history of cards sold on market, there is listed at least the removed games that contains steam cards but free-to-play

Comment: You can still see all the games you played to in your game time.

Comment: Where? Each time i removed a game, it doesn't appear anymore on lib, game list or anywhere in steam official site even in purchase and product key activations history

Comment: I don't really have the english names but when you go to your profile you have the "recent activities" section with games you played recently and the time you spent on it. If you scroll down, you can click to see more and it will order the games you played to in function of the time you spent on it.
Is it what you're searching for ?

Comment: Is your library filter set to "installed"? All my games are there, but I set the removed category to something else to filter them out.

Comment: Nope, @Yorik I'm not telling about steam client. I' dont "uninstall" the game but I removed that using help.steampowered.com. If i want play, i'll need to buy again. But where that games are listed?

Comment: If you go into the 'all game' tab under library you should see all games ever owned. The ones that are "greyed out" are ones that are no longer installed (or never were) and the ones white are currently installed. 
If you are in the 'installed' tab under library, you won't see any uninstalled or removed games.

Comment: i edited the question for more clarity

Comment: I just tried the suggestion and it doesn't seem to work.  I bought a game a while ago and refunded it, I can't then see it under my All Games activity.  However Steam does keep some sort of record of time played because another game I refunded (and have subsequently re-purchased) shows the amount of time I did play it.  I figured it might have been some form of caching, but this is a new PC so it's not a file stored locally... unless steam cloud factors into time played?

Comment: I'm going to say the only way to find this information out is to look at your steam transaction history.

Comment: Well that won't tell you how long you played either @Timmy Jim.

Comment: @MattR that isn't what the OP is looking for anyway.

Comment: @TimmyJim Most games that I enabled by product key, do not directly purchase in the store. These games were listed under * "Viewing licenses and product key activations" page: https://store.steampowered.com/account/licenses/ when I remove a game, it disappers from this list. To test, an hour ago I recovered a game and it appers again in the list, but the other removed games are still hidden.

Comment: had similar issue trying to find list of revoked (acquired via 3rd party) game keys, none such under one's account (+revoked ones just disappear from activations page). The popup about revocation doesn't show the date you had added it so it's harder with just the game name to find the transaction (game may have come from a bundle), even if you keep all e-mails from e-stores and paypal etc. Eventually found addition/revocation dates from help, via https://help.steampowered.com/wizard/HelpWithGameIssue/?appid=xxx&issueid=126 - could automate passing appid for all games one has and parse reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steam does not offer a way of viewing these games natively. There are, however, some things you can do:

- When buying games, you receive an email from Steam. Search your email for

  ```
  from:noreply@steampowered.com purchase --community
  ```

  or in other words, emails sent by noreply@steampowered.com with the keyword "purchase" and without "community" (market) in it.
- If you did buy a game via other means, your email likely has emails with the keywords "steam" and "key" in it.
- An untested method would be to use the steam web api to iterate over all apps they have in store. This may or may not be against their TOS (I haven't read that closely). To find those app ids you may use a site like steamdb. Steamdb has a little over 53k games in their database, which is a big but not unmanagable task. I don't know if GetPlayerAchievements does actually display achievements for games deleted from your account, but it is worth a try.

  - https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API
  - http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetPlayerAchievements/v0001/?appid=440&key=xxxx&steamid=xxxx

Comment: Wow, great idea. I am a software developer, I will try to do something using the Steam API as soon as I have some free time.Thank you so much

Comment: if you have a SteamID for me to test I'd like to test that API idea. Any idea roughly what game would be removed though? There might be more ways for it to work, though it seems @anisanwesley has looked into quite a few in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/301100/757990)

Comment: Here i've got the steamID: https://steamid.io and Steam api key can be getten here: https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey just replace the values on urls to that you want,Good luck, I'm still hopeful

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but maybe it can help someone else.

Deleted games for which you unlocked one or more achievements still appear in the achievement showcase on your profile. When you're trying to add an achievement there, in the list of game you should see those deleted games though when you select them, there won't be any achievement to display.

Comment: here's a tool that leverages this behaviour to diff which games are missing from various trackers out there: https://completionist.me/steam/recover

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the Steam API as @Sumurai8 said, using this "all games list". I was writing many ways to get removed games achievements, but unfortunately there is no way to get them. That's all that Steam responds to me when the game is removed:

```
{
    "playerstats": {
        "error": "Requested app has no stats",
        "success": false
    }
}
```

At least you can retrieve them using help.steampowered.com, but to get a list of removed games you must remember one by one

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Nice try! But, this is more of a comment on the other answer.  You should summarize it, and post it as so.  You could probably get rid of the code as well.