# Is there a way to see a list of every game I have ever owned on Steam?

Tags: steam, pc

Is there a way to see a list of every game I have ever owned on Steam? This includes games I have refunded, free games I've removed the license for, and free weekend games that I didn't end up buying.

If I edit an achievement showcase, I can see almost such a list, but it only shows games I have earned at least one achievement for. There is no way to know if, for example, a game I refunded a year ago and promptly forgot about recently added achievements.

Comment: I think this is sort of related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300761/is-there-a-way-to-list-my-removed-games-on-steam/301100#301100

Comment: Do you consider every free weekend game to be "owned", since you could technically install and play any of them at some point?

Comment: @Batophobia no. If I didn't download it, then it's not associated with my account, so it's none of my concern

Comment: @TimmyJim thanks for the link, the answer about the steam api may be useful. I'm a programmer, so I'm perfectly willing to get my hands dirty with json api requests (as long as there is adequate documentation). I don't need to see the achievement list, as there are other ways I can check that (store page, showcase edit)

Comment: Give it a shot - I'd be curious to see your solution if you can come up with one.  It seems the person who tried to use the API didn't get very far, but they were looking for achievement information so perhaps it may be possible to do what you want.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't seem to show weekend games that weren't purchased, you could use the purchase history page (https://store.steampowered.com/account/history/).

On that page, you will see every game you have purchased, including ones that have been refunded.

Comment: The purchase history shows monetary transactions you've made, which even includes buys and sales in the community market. There is also a separate list of the licenses you own which includes free games etc, but the licenses in that list disappear if you remove the free game from your account IIRC. It used to be that uninstalling a free game would remove it from your library, but it has since changed: you have to explicitly remove the game now.